# MongoDB slow in fetching from database

Tags: database, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm using MongoDB in combination with Meteor + React and the result fetching takes like 5 sec even on a small database.

This happens only on the production server (AWS) and it works instantly on the local machine.

In order to fetch the results, I'm using the following code.

`return{ cand : Job.find({thejob:props.id}).fetch() };`

and to see if the array has been loaded, I use the following code on the frontend side.

`if(!this.props.cand){return(<div>Loading....</div>)}`

but the Loading.... takes like 5 sec on the server always. The database is a small one with less than 1000 records.

Comment: Is your machine connected to a remote mongo? or running on the VM itself? it might be a VM performance issue

Comment: What is your AWS setup like?

Comment: @Deano I am running it on the VM itself.

Comment: @Jankapunkt It's a t2.large instance running Ubuntu 16.04 on Apache server.

Comment: @squareRoot try and use htop see what else might be running on the VM, you may also try using MongoDB atlas (they provide free hosted DB on AWS free tier) to off that load off your server

Comment: @Deano is there any problem if I run the app using npm start on server rather than building it and then hosting

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar experiences. The performance is pretty good when you run the queries in the local machine. If the query is slower in platforms like AWS and not on the local, it's mostly due to the **Network latency**.

Comment: Hmm.. So is there any way to solve this? It takes like 5 sec for a query which is not at all agreeable on applications that needs to be scaled. I see mongoDB being used by many large scale companies and they seem to have a fast working DB with lot more records in them..

Comment: @squareRoot if the cause of this delay is network latency (as it appears so as you mentioned that localhost queries are fast), it is entirely outside the control of any application code or database you have. The only way to "solve" this is to upgrade your network, or putting your application closer to your database in network terms.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha but it is running on a top of the line AWS server, not the basic one or anything like that with high-speed network access. both the app and the database are on the same server. very close by.

Comment: @squareRoot in that case, you would need to hire a consultant that can check everything in your deployment. There's not much anyone can do without access to your deployment to solve this. All the typical ones (indexes, network issues) you have said are not the issue, so a consultant is the only solution at this point.

Comment: @squareRoot, were able to resolve this latency issue? I'm experiencing a similar situation where my query execution time is less than a second, but it takes more than 40 seconds to in network response

Comment: @Zeeshan Yes, just do the queries on the server and get back the results using a Meteor call.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there isn't an index on the `thejob` field.

First check if there is an index on `thejob` field

```
db.job.getIndexes()
```

If there is none, simply create one

```
db.job.createIndex({thejob:1})
```

Comment: But in that case, the same query should be slow on the local machine as well, but the case is different. It's lightning fast on my local machine.

Comment: ` {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "meteor.candidateDB"
 },
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "canID" : 1,
   "username" : 1
  },
  "name" : "canID_1_username_1",
  "ns" : "meteor.candidateDB"
 },
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "canID" : 1
  },
  "name" : "canID_1",
  "ns" : "meteor.candidateDB"
 }
]`